# Regex Get Rid of Hyphens Between Quotes

Tags: json, regex

I get a json string back from a device, the string has hyphens in the defintion names and I want to remove that...

Current I have

```
\"(.+?)\":
```

But that gets everything within "":  I want only the hyphen in there, not all the text. I know I am close just having trouble because regex always confuses me.  Below I would like to correct serial-number to serialnumber but not value-2....help!

```
{
  "result": {
    "Response": {
      "info": {
        "serial-number": "xyz",
        "value1": "value-2",
```

Comment: Probably easier to let your JSON parser process the JSON and then map the property names in the result. What JSON parser are you using?

Comment: It seems to me, that you might reach the goal easier by *string.replace()* or the corresponding method.

Comment: Use @guidot way.. i.e `"value-2".replace("-","")` returns `value2` but if there exists multiple hypens use `"va-lue-2".replace(/-/g,"")`

Comment: I am using newtonsoft json parser.  My problem is it comes from an external device and I am parsing the json to class objects.  Some of the values are numbers and one is -1.  So if I do a blanket .replace I lose the -1....so I need to do something bettween quotes and colon....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match

```
/"([^"]*)-([^"]*)":/
```

And then replace with just the two submatches.
See http://www.regexpal.com/?fam=95143

This is the sort of js code that should work:

```
json = json.replace(/"([^"]*)-([^"]*)":/g,'"$1$2"');
```

Here's another version, using a lookahead:

```
json = json.replace(/-(?=[^"]*":)/g,"");
```

This assumes there's never a space between the closing `"` and the `:`

Comment: Is there any way to match exactly on the hyphen so I can just use regex.replace?

Comment: I've added a version with a lookahead which only matches the hyphen.

Comment: Lookahead did exactly what I wanted.  Boy I hate regex and still have a hard time understanding it :)